How to make AWS Lambda / API Gateway return an image?
Original question
I'm writing a Lambda function and I want it to return an image and I cannot make it work.
Usually, given the URL of an ordinary image, in Python, I can load the image using PILLOW and BytesIO this way:
response = requests.get(IMAGE_URL)
pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
pil_image.show()

If I use my Lambda + API Gateway endpoint, the Python code I need to write is:
response = requests.post(API_URL, json={"url": IMAGE_URL})
pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(response.content)))
pil_image.show()

If I don't decode the content, it doesn't work.
I have done the following:

Response of the Lambda function:

file_object = BytesIO()
pil_image.save(file_object, format="JPEG", quality=95)
image_str = base64.b64encode(file_object.getvalue()).decode("ascii")

response = {
    "isBase64Encoded": True,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
    "body": image_str,
}


In API Gateway, I created a new resource and a POST method with the following properties:


Integration type: Lambda
Lambda proxy integration: Activated


In API Gateway, in the newly created POST method, in the Method response, I added the Content-type image/jpeg

In API Gateway, in the API settings, I added the image/jpeg binary media types


I've read that API Gateway is supposed to convert the image, but maybe I'm wrong.
I don't get what I am missing.
I have tried to follow different tutorials, including AWS ones, and yet, I couldn't make it work as some options are not available in the console. Here are some of the links:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html
AWS API Gateway and Lambda to return image
AWS API Gateway base64Decode produces garbled binary?
Edit / Modifications
After trying many things and I modified the steps as follow:

Unchanged
I created a GET method instead of a POST (should not change anything)
I did not add the Content-type image/jpeg in the Method response
I added the */* binary media types in the API settings

These steps seem to be working and I am able to load the image from the response.
The only problem with this solution is that API Gateway encodes the payload and I need to do something like json.loads(base64.b64decode(event["body"]))["url"]) in the Lambda function to access the input URL.
Maybe there's a better way?
